# Perl sequential requets-responds for HTTP client

Tags: perl, sockets, io

folks!
Currently I need to maintain some zoo of scripts. Now I need to perform a sequential request-respond operation from a HTTP-like server. The original script was a single request-respond task, so no problem at all. But now I need to make 3 different requests, parse responds and store them to PostgreSQL. But for example, lets think we will tackle google.

```
$socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => "google.com:80", KeepAlive => 1);

$socket->write("GET / HTTP/1.1" . $EOL);
$socket->write("Connection: keep-alive" . $EOL);
$socket->write($EOL);
$socket->flush();

while($sockbuff = $socket->getline)
{
  print ("$sockbuff");
  $recvbuff = $recvbuff.$sockbuff;
}

print("- REQUEST 1 -\n");

$socket->write("GET / HTTP/1.1" . $EOL);

while($sockbuff = $socket->getline)
{
  print ("$sockbuff");
  $recvbuff = $recvbuff.$sockbuff;
}
```

But, since the Connection: keep-alive specified, process will never get out from the first while(read) cycle and therefore will never send second request and will wait until thread will be terminated by outside (I need to poll of about 350 such servers, so, the whole process is threaded).
On the other way, if I force socket to operate in nonblocking mode, I get only the first line.
Can anybody suggest how I can make a sequential write-read operations in Perl keeping in mind, that this is HTTP-like protocol.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `LWP`? Which is built in to perl, and quite good for HTTP based tasks.

Comment: Well, not really. I have a poller written on pure C with multi socket and just want to make something bare-bone.

Comment: OK. I'll post something with an LWP example them. The real strength of perl is the vast amount of (maintained) library code out there. LWP is 'core' perl, so it's well looked after and ubiquitous.

Comment: LWP is not a core module.

Comment: Hmm, no it isn't. I think I've never noticed, because it's one that gets installed in virtually every build I've 'perled' on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody suggest how I can make a sequential write-read operations in Perl keeping in mind, that this is HTTP-like protocol.

Use LWP::UserAgent, Mojo::UserAgent or similar modules.

If you really want to do it by your own:

- Read the standard, e.g. RFC 2616 (or newer RFC7230..7235).
- Learn how the length of the body is defined. Watch out for `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.
- Read the body until the end defined in the response and not until connection end or until it stalls. Then send the next request but watch out for any information in the `Connection` header which say that the connection will be closed.

> But for example, lets think we will tackle google.

Even harder because you will have to deal with HTTPS here, so IO::Socket::INET will not help you. In this case you would need IO::Socket::SSL.

Comment: So, the only option I have (in case of plane socket implementation) is to get the body size from Content-Length and then stop receiving after a specified bytes are put to buffer?

Comment: Kind of. Don't forget to implement Transfer-Encoding chunked if you use HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I'd suggest you're doing this the hard way. Perl comes with a lovely library called [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) - which lets you do 'web stuff'.

With `LWP::UserAgent` your code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1 );
my $response = $agent->get('http://www.google.com');

if ( $response->is_success ) {
    print $response ->content();
}
else {
    print "Failed: ", $response->status_line(), "\n";
}
```

And you can quite trivially extend to multiple URLs I'm sure :).

Comment: I will probably try to ues LWP::UserAgent rather then implementing this mechanism with plane sockets (I'm not that grate perl programmer). And we'll see if this works.